# Checkbox values are NOT passing to PHP using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

This is my HTML CODE(ONLY CheckBOX part)  i need to check multiple choices from user and send it to php using ajax.then i need to post a mail to administrator

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label>Preferred method of contact : </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-check">

        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" id="color" value="Whatsapp">Whatsapp

        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">

            <input type="checkbox" name="color" id="color" value="Viber">Viber
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" id="color" value="E-Mail">E-Mail
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

AND this is Ajax Part to SEND values to php. in my contact us form NAME PHONENO ADDRESS and drop-downs are working fine with ajax and php but only this check box part not working .

```
<script>
function _(id) {
   return document.getElementById(id);
}

function submitForm() {
   _("mybtn").disabled = true;
   _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
   var formdata = new FormData();

   formdata.append("n", _("n").value);
   formdata.append("e", _("e").value);
   formdata.append("m", _("m").value);
   formdata.append("no", _("no").value);
   formdata.append("exampleSelect1", _("exampleSelect1").value);
   formdata.append("exampleSelect2", _("exampleSelect2").value);
   formdata.append("exampleSelect3", _("exampleSelect3").value);

   formdata.append("color", _("color").value);

   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.open("POST", "example_parser.php");
   ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
         if (ajax.responseText == "success") {
            _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks ' + _("n").value + ', your message has been sent.</h2>';
         } else {
            _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            _("mybtn").disabled = false;
         }
      }
   }
   ajax.send(formdata);
}
</script>
```

And this is my PHP code From php page. i need to pass all checkbox result to this php part and declarer to a variable then i can use it for mailing .

```
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['m']) ){
$n = $_POST['n']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
$e = $_POST['e'];
$no = $_POST['no'];
$m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
$pkg = $_POST['exampleSelect1'];
$cnty = $_POST['exampleSelect2'];
$how = $_POST['exampleSelect3'];

$var = $_POST['color'];
```

Comment: You can't use same id. Id must be unique.

Comment: Can you try to make aJax after checking the checkbox. I think if checkbox are not checked its value takes as blank on ajax request.

Comment: i got Answer . NOW its Working :)  Thnku anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you have three elements with the same id="color".
Then:

```
document.getElementById("color")
```

Will always return first of them, and no matter is it checked or not.
It's good idea to declare another function:

```
function __(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Then, you could write:

```
var colors = __('input[name="color"]:checked');
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
   result.push(colors[i].value);
}

formdata.append("color", result);
```

Comment: WOwww really its Working :) thnku Sooo much :) :)